# How to dynamically set the background colour of a text layer/div in Slider Revolution from Advanced Custom Field Colour Picker?

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, slider-revolution

OUTLINE: I want to dynamically set the background colour of a text layer/div in Slider Revolution based on the colour a user pics on the post

I have a div using Text Layer in Slider Revolution (SR). The slider shows posts from "Events" - a Custom Post Type.

The background of this div needs to change according to the background colour in ACF field by user (event_background_color) set in the Custom Post Type.

In SR I have the text layer content with this code:

```
<div class="primary-background"></div>
```

and in WordPress Customise – Additional CSS I have:

```
.primary-background {
    background-color: <?php the_field('event_main_color'); ?>;
}
```

However, the obvious issue with the above is that php is not parsed by css.

I have also tried;

```
<div style="background-color:{{meta:event_main_color}};" class="primary-background"></div>
```

But to no avail.

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Have you tried adding this inside a style tag in the html maybe in the header.php file?

```
<style>
    .primary-background {
        background-color: <?php the_field('event_main_color'); ?>;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I have tried that code already but I am applying the code within Slider Revolution layer content on a page that isn't the posts - 3 posts need to loop through the posts within Slider Revolution and apply the background colour according to the ACF hex field. Tried get_field() function also. A JS developer came up with a brilliant working solution BUT it wasn't compatible with Slider Revolution timeline animation changes. However, I CAN print out the 3 different correct hex values on each 3 slides using: 
    [acf field="event_main_color" post_id="{{id}}"]
    {{meta:event_main_color}}

Comment: Yes, tried that, thanks. But I need to apply the CSS change within Slider Revolution. The code you have suggested only works on the post page itself. I am trying to generate for 3 different posts in a slider on a page that isn't any of the posts - therefore it needs to either loop through somehow or use Slider Revoultion custom meta tag/acf shortcode somehow.